# Render a Views row ID using NID (Node ID)

Tags: 7, views, theming

I can easily add NID (Node ID) as a field in my view and then render it as a class for the Views Row using replacement patterns for the row class of an unformatted typical view. (See screen capture).

[image]

However, I'd like to render the NID as an **ID** for each row for use for some special theming I am doing. If I use devel themer, I see my template is `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` so I can of course copy this template into my theme's template folder with a custom name specific to my view and then theme it.

The relevant line of code in the template that renders the row class is:

```
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
```

If I change it to:

```
<div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?> 
    id="<?php print $fields['nid']->content ?>">
```

...However, this does not work as I don't think fields are available at this level in the views row.

So essentially right now my rendered output is:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first mynid-63">
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even mynid-64">
```

... when I'd like it to be

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first" id="mynid-63">
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-even" id="mynid-64">
```

My question, is there a way to just render the associated NID where I want it as an id other then the method I am trying to use?

Comment: maybe I am missing something but why can't you use row-nid-[nid] (or whatever prefix you want) in your Row Class and then use .row-nid-64 (or whatever nid ##) instead of #row-nid-64 in your CSS? Eg, what kind of theming are you doing that requires an ID instead of a CLASS?

Comment: @Jimajamma No that won't work, I need an ID as specified in my question above, I am doing a custom responsive grid gallery and each row needs a unique ID attribute for later use. The NID is perfect for this as it's always going to be unique and relevant to the data.

Comment: Also, regardless of the outcome, be careful with numeric CSS IDs or classes -- lots of browsers don't like them, eg #64 is illegal/ignored.

Comment: @Jimajamma - of course that's just an example, I can easily preface the NID (once I get it) with a textual name...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most Views templates, the entire `$view` object is available.  So, assuming you have a `nid` field in the row, you should be able to access it with something like this:

```
$view->result[$id]->nid
```

so, give

```
id="my-nid-is-<?php print $view->result[$id]->nid; ?>">
```

a try in your template.

If this doesn't work exactly, a `print_r($view->result);` up at the top of the template will give you a gander at what you have to work with.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed, works great thanks. My google-foo failed me on this one but now that I know what I am looking for, there's probably an API doc somewhere for this.

Comment: glad I could help out!  Some Views-foo:  there will (almost always) be a nid field in the results when there is a node in there so you might not even need to include the nid field directly unless you need it in your View for something other than theming.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this inside a module (without using a custom template) ?

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't think so since the html is generated inside the template, and the default ones provided don't include any id tags in them at all.

Answer (score 1):

The NID is added via the format settings as last in the class string; ' $classes_array[$id]

Get the last class in the class string (which is the Nid added via views)
Then just add the $last as proper ID to the row after the classes

so change this to:

```
<div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
```

to:

```
<div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { 
    $class_string = explode(' ', $classes_array[$id]);
    $last = end($class_string); 
    print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"' . ' id="' . $last . '"';  
 } ?>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `views-view-fields--[name].tpl.php` for construct the main row div. So, put in your `views-view-fields:

```
<div id="<?php print $row->nid; ?>">
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
    <?php print $field->separator; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
    <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
    <?php print $field->content; ?>
  <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The main problem is that you have two `<div>` tags. So you can choose to delete the div into `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php`.

Comment: Well if I delete the div in `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php`, that's no good as then I loose all my nice row classes and I don't think I can pop that code into the fields template. That's "robbing Peter to pay Paul" as it were...

Comment: you're right ;)